# get Xpath value from a html variable

Tags: javascript, xpath, web-scraping

in these days im working in a project.
I am trying to scrape some data but unfortunately so far without success. I got the source code of the page in order to get the data, but I don't know how to get the xpath value since "html" is in a variable, can someone help me? I would appreciate it so much

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<p id="bio"></p>
<script>
    $.getJSON('https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://ricette.giallozafferano.it/Tiramisu.html') + '&callback=?', function (data) {
        var htmlString = data.contents;
        var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
        console.log(doc);
        
        // document.getElementById("bio").textContent = xpath;
        // XAPTH /html/body/div[2]/main/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span[2]
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `document.evaluate` and pass the HTML you have parsed as second argument:

```
document.evaluate('/html/body/div[2]/main/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span[2]', doc);
```

Comment: thank you for reply but I can't implement it, maybe I'm doing something wrong. Could you tell me how to implement it please?